# How to pull ObjectId from an Array in a BsonDocument with C# MongoDriver 2.5

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to port over JavaScript code that interacts with a MongoDb to C# .NET and having problems with a delete/pull operation.  I can't seem to figure out how to iterate over the **Ponies** array and remove a single ObjectId by matching to a passed in ObjectId.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c60e"),
    "Location" : "rainbowland",
    "Ponies" : [ 
        ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e83c"), 
        ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e860"), 
        ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e83d")
    ]
}
```

I've tried several different ways based on what I've found online but nothing seems to work.  When I check the collection to see if **388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e860** was removed from the Ponies array I see that it wasn't removed.  Everytime I execute the code and look at the **ModifiedCount** for **resultPonies** it shows zero.  Two examples of what I've tried doing are below.

```
        var pony = new Pony() { Id = new ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e860") }
        var pullPonies = Builders<Ranch>.Update.PullFilter(x => x.Ponies, 
            y => y.Id == pony.Id);
        var filterPonies = Builders<Ranch>.Filter.Where(x => true);
        var resultPonies = _context.Ranches.UpdateMany(filterPonies, pullPonies);
```

**OR**

```
        var pullPonies = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PullFilter("Ponies",
             Builders<ObjectId>.Filter.Eq("ObjectId", pony.Id));
        var filterPonies = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(x => true);
        var resultPonies = _context.Ranches.UpdateMany(filterPonies, pullPonies);
```

Here is the JavaScript code that I believe works but haven't been able to test yet.

```
db.collection("Ranches").update({}, {$pull: {Ponies: pony._id}}, {multi: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution for the problem.  Since I'm not actually going to be filtering within the array of objects, they are all ObjectIds in a BsonArray, I need to find where the value in the array matches the given ObjectId.  In those cases the array item should be pulled out.  If the object in the array had other properties then I would probably want to use the PullFilter.  But in this case I don't need to filter the additional level.  That is at least what I believe I was doing wrong.  Here are the solutions

```
    var ponyId = new ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e860");
    var pullPonies = Builders<Ranch>.Update.Pull(x => x.Ponies, ponyId);
    // This line is to retrieve all Ranch objects in the collection
    var filterPonies = Builders<Ranch>.Filter.Where(x => true);
    var resultPonies = _context.Ranches.UpdateMany(filterPonies, pullPonies);
```

**Or**

```
    var ponyId = new ObjectId("388e8a66fe2af4e35c24e860");
    var pullPonies = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pull("Ponies", ponyId));
    // This line is to retrieve all Ranch objects in the collection
    var filterPonies = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Where(x => true);
    var resultPonies = _context.Ranches.UpdateMany(filterPonies, pullPonies);
```